# Classes in Javascript - Properties undefined after method passed as argument

Tags: javascript, class, methods, properties, undefined

Can anybody shed a light on why I get the first console message: '1 .list-group-item' on class instantiation, but after button press of '.remove_track', I get this.DOM.TrackItems as undefined? Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

```
class MyList
        constructor() {
            this.DOM = {
                ParentNode: '#mylist',
                AddTrackButton: '#add_track',
                RemoveTrackButtons: '.remove_track',
                TrackItems: '.list-group-item'
           };

            this.bind(this.DOM.ParentNode, this.DOM.RemoveTrackButtons, 'click', this.removeTrack);

        };

        //jQuery on/off methods
        bind(parentSelector, childSelector, eventName, functionName) {
            console.log('1 ' + this.DOM.TrackItems);
            $(parentSelector).on(eventName, childSelector, functionName);
        };

        unbind(parentSelector, childSelector, eventName, functionName){
            $(parentSelector).off(eventName, childSelector, functionName);
        }

        removeTrack(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log('2 ' + this.DOM.TrackItems);
        }
}
```

//EDIT:

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rr9umtc8/11/)

Comment: It works as expected to me.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Ele - jsfiddle included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the scope of context `this`, that approach is using the context of the handler from event `click`, specifically the clicked button rather than the context of the class `MyList`.

An alternative is to bind the context using the function `bind`:

```
                   +----- This is the object MyList
                   |
                   v
functionName.bind(this); <---- This call returns a new function bound with 
              ^                the specific context.
              |
              +---- This function binds the context
```

If you need to get access to the clicked element, you can use the param `event`.

```js
class MyList {
  constructor() {
    this.DOM = {
      ParentNode: '#mylist',
      AddTrackButton: '#add_track',
      RemoveTrackButtons: '.remove_track',
      TrackItems: '.list-group-item',
      Output: '#output'
    }

    this.bind(this.DOM.ParentNode, this.DOM.RemoveTrackButtons, 'click', this.removeTrack);
  };

  bind(parentSelector, childSelector, eventName, functionName) {
    $(this.DOM.Output).html('Called Bind'); //works
    // This is the line with a fix.
    $(parentSelector).on(eventName, childSelector, functionName.bind(this));
  };

  unbind(parentSelector, childSelector, eventName, functionName) {
    $(this.DOM.Output).html('Called Unbind');
    $(parentSelector).off(eventName, childSelector, functionName);
  }

  removeTrack(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(evt.target);
    console.log(this); // This is just to show the content of this.
    $(this.DOM.Output).html('Called removeTrack');
  }
}

x = new MyList();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mylist">
  <button class="remove_track">
  HELLO
  </button>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's outstanding. Thanks very much Ele.